# Azure Function App - How to defer and re-receive an unprocessable message

Tags: c#, messaging, azure-iot-hub, azure-function-app

I have the following Azure architecture:

**IoTDevices ---> IoTHub ---> Function App**

where:

- **IoTDevices**: collect sensor data and send them to IoTHub
- **IoTHub**: receives the data from devices and delivers those data to Function App (using Event Hub-compatible endpoint)
- **Function App**: performs some processing on the received data

now in the Function App I have something like this:

```
public static void Run([IoTHubTrigger("messages/events", Connection = "EventHubConnection")]EventData message, TraceWriter log)
{
  string messageString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(message.GetBytes());
  //do some processing with messageString as input
}
```

for several reasons, there are cases in which the processing can not be performed; I'd like to save the message `SequenceNumber` and defer the message so that later, when the processing become available again, I can re-receive the message from the IoTHub.
So summarizing, the questions are:

- how can I defer my message?
- how can I re-receive/re-read the message given the `SequenceNumber`?

Comment: An Event Hub doesn't do that natively.  Either read from a Service Bus topic or queue, or write the failed messages to some other store, like a Service Bus topic or queue, or a database.

Comment: ah, bad news for me; ok I'll probably go with database storage, but honestly I would have liked to simply defer the message and ask the EventHub to provide it later...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/message-deferral

> Deferred messages remain in the main queue along with all other active messages (unlike dead-letter messages that live in a subqueue), but they can no longer be received using the regular Receive/ReceiveAsync functions. Deferred messages can be discovered via message browsing if an application loses track of them.

Comment: Hi @Neil, I've already read that part of the documentation but I am wondering how to move from ```EventData``` (what I have now in my code) to ```BrokeredMessage``` (what I need to perform deferral and re-receive)

Comment: `BrokeredMessage` is only for ServiceBus messages - IoT Hub messages are based on EventHub. So you would first need to route the IoT Hub messages into a Service Bus.